# Jasper Reports - How to get JRXML components with mixed styles or dynamic widths on text boxes?

Tags: jasper-reports

When buliding jasper reports JRXML files I want to be able to have a row of dynamically width'd text boxes of mixing styles. It does not seem like Jasper supports that so I'm stuck with this:

[image]

Notice how I used two static text boxes for this display *with fixed widths*. This is because I cannot mix the bold + normal font styles inside a component.

I would rather something like this:

[image]

Where the NOW() and $P{name} will automatically stretch out and look real nice.

Note: I cannot use the HTML component due to this issue http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540569/html-component-font and https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/4411-0

Is there a way to code JRXML files with dynamically width'd Textboxes?

Comment: I removed the iText tag as it's a pure Jasper-Reports problem; iText as such doesn't have any problem mixing styles.

Comment: I put iText so you would take a look. Hehe sorry i'm a cheater.

Comment: i'm just kidding. i did wonder if this had itext implications because of the problem with the html component not pulling in my custom font. is that an itext thing?

Comment: AFAIK JasperReports depends on `PdfGraphics2D` which is an iText subclass of Java's `Graphics2D`. If there are problems with HTML, then these problems probably find their origin in `java.awt.Graphics2D`. I don't know for sure, I'm not very familiar with the way JasperReports is designed.

Comment: So perhaps if i load the fonts in a Java awt like way it will start working. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can mix styles using markup in a single text box. Jasper supports (simple) HTML, RTF and a custom jasper-styling.

Check the "markup" property.

But I am not aware that you could insert artificial borders around the values when using a single textbox.

Comment: I got it. `styled` worked. HTML did not work. The problem with those was the font i was using wasn't working. It is a commercial custom font. but when i used the `<font>` attribute it worked fine. The `<style>` element did NOT work for me. The key was to set the font face to the FONT name i added to jasper. once i did that, everything works.